# regex find and replace notepad++

Tags: html, regex

I am using notepad++

The regex must only be applies to href tag with "video" in the path

How would I change this

```
href="../Video/000_Movies/assets/001_CCC_Jesus_Film.html"
href="../Video/000_Movies/assets/003_Hope.html"
href="../Video/000_Movies/assets/004_CCC_Magdelena.html"
href="../Books/PDF/419_ROI_One_God_One_Message.pdf"
href="../Books/PDF/405_MUH_Truth_07.3_Epistles_Wisdom.pdf"
```

to this

```
href="../Video/000_Movies/assets/playlist.html#&panel1-1"
href="../Video/000_Movies/assets/playlist.html#&panel1-1"
href="../Video/000_Movies/assets/playlist.html#&panel1-1"
href="../Books/PDF/419_ROI_One_God_One_Message.pdf"
href="../Books/PDF/405_MUH_Truth_07.3_Epistles_Wisdom.pdf"
```

Comment: do you want `video` or `Video` they are different things you know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace:

```
href="\.\./Video/000_Movies/assets/(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"
```

with

```
href="../Video/000_Movies/assets/playlist.html#&panel1-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Search:

```
href="([^"]+)/[^/]+\.html"
```

Replace with:

```
href="\1/playlist.html#&panel1-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for :  `(/Video.+/).+\.html`

and replace by :  `\1playlist.html#&panel1-1`